# MessengerExtensions.requestCloseBrowser() won't close in desktop

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot

When i try to close the webview with this code:

```
MessengerExtensions.requestCloseBrowser(function success() {}, function failure(err) {
  alert('error closing the window: ' + err); // error closing the window: 
  console.log(err); // doesn't print
  window.close();
});
```

it closes the webview in iOS, but pops an alert when i try from desktop.
My domain is white-listed, messenger_extensions = true and i enter the page from the desktop messenger and it still doesn't work.

I had before the same problem, but opposite (window closed on desktop, but not on iOS) while trying to use fetch(), and this problem started when started using $.ajax()
before MessengerExtensions.requestCloseBrowser() was invoked from a fetch's promise, and now it's invoked from ajax's success function.

I had to switch fetch with ajax because it didn't work on iOS

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A day later an error code of 2071011 started to show up, again, only in desktop browsers.
I managed to find a workaround the problem by using window.top.close(); when MessengerExtensions.requestCloseBrowser() fails
It does the same trick on Chrome and asks the user before close on Edge

Answer (score 0):

```
window.extAsyncInit = function() {
   MessengerExtensions.requestCloseBrowser(function success() {
     window.close(); // webview closed
   }, function error(err) {print ('an error occured');}
   );

 };
```

From the documentation on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/extensions,

> window.extAsyncInit() will be called when the Messenger Extensions JS
>   SDK is done loading. You can use this as a trigger to call other
>   functions available in the SDK.